# function identity: does $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2} = x+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Can you tell me how to resolve the (apparent) paradox that the function:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$$

is identical to the function:

$$g(x) = x+2$$

because by factoring the numerator:

$$f(x) = \frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{x-2} = x+2$$

But $f(x)$ can't be identical to $g(x)$ since the former is undefined at $x = 2$ and the latter is not ?
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: They are identical EXCEPT at $x=2$ where one is defined and the other isn't. Cancelling isn't valid when top and bottom are both zero.

Comment: A paradox, a paradox, a most ingenious paradox! Ah ha ha ha ha ha ha, a most ingenious paradox! —Sir William Schwenck Gilbert, *The Pirates of Penzance*

Answer (score 11):

They are not identical. The first one has what we call a *removable singularity* at $x=2$. There are times when we don't care about the difference, though, and we just consider a removable singularity to be filled in.

Comment: To be pedantic, it's not a removable discontinuity, it's a removable singularity. The function is not discontinuous at 2.

Comment: "Singularity" is the right word. I think correct would be to say it's neither continuous nor discontinuous at 2, right?

Comment: If it is not defined there, it certainly cannot be continuous or discontinuous there. A removable discontinuity would be if we defined $f(2) = 7$ or something – a place where the function is discontinuous, but this can be "fixed" by changing only that value.

Comment: Edited to reflect your comment

Answer (score 9):

By defintion two functions are said to be identical if they have the same domain  and the same image so $f\neq g$ but we may say that $f$ is extended at $2$ by continuity on the function $g$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Is it the case then that: (x-2)/(x-2) <> 1, because 1 is "always defined". That would mean that 1(x-2) <> (x-2), and so (x-2) <> (x-2) ?

Comment: If I understand your question, I say yes it is like $2\times 0=3\times 0$ but $\frac{2\times 0}{0}$ doesn't make sense and it's not equal $3$.

Comment: @Mike: $\frac{x-2}{x-2}$ is not the same function as $1$, but you *cannot* say from this that $1(x-2)$ and $(x-2)$ are different functions! See BenMillwood's answer; the real issue is one of notation: instead of specifying the domain and then a rule to compute the function inside the domain, we're implicitly following a notational convention of *inferring* the domain from the rule. If we actually specify the domain of each function, all these apparent paradoxes go away: for instance, $\frac{(x-2)}{(x-2)}$ is a function on the domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus2$, and $1$ is on domain $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Convincing answer for any student. +1

Answer (score 4):

This is largely a difficulty of notation. Your definition doesn't explicitly state what to do in the case $x = 2$. Some people would take this omission to mean $f$ is undefined there; others would take it to mean $f$ is the natural thing for it to be, the only value that makes it continuous at that point. Usually the latter interpretation is harmless, in which case the two functions really are equal.

Supposing we don't like this imprecision, and we demand that $f$ is undefined at $2$ so has a strictly smaller domain than $g$. In this case, they are certainly not equal, but you have to be careful. I'd say that $f \not= g$, but it's wrong to say that $f(x) \not= g(x)$, so in particular it's wrong to say that $\frac{x^2 - 4}{x-2} \not= x + 2$: either the equation is true or meaningless, depending on what you think $x$ is.

Comment: I find this the clearest answer to the question. As you say, the issue is of notation — the fact that we're implicitly inferring the domain from the rule rather than specifying the domain, but this is only a matter of convention.

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to think of a function of one variable like this as a set of ordered pairs. Here, $(2,4)\in g$, but $(2,4)\notin f$. So, despite the fact that all other elements of $g$ are also elements of $f$, $f$ and $g$ are not the same functions.

---

**10 years later....**

> "Definition 3.3.7 (Equality of functions). Two functions f : X → Y , g
> : X → Y with the same domain and range [codomain] are said to be
> equal, f = g, if and only if f(x) = g(x) for all x ∈ X. "
> --Terence Tao, "Analysis I", p.51

My formalization:

$\forall f, g, X, Y: [f: X\to Y~~\land ~~ g: X \to Y \implies [f=g \iff \forall x\in X: f(x)=g(x)]]$

By this definition, we can determine whether two functions are equal or not only if they have the same domain and range/codomain. Since the domains of $f$ and $g$, as defined above, are *not* the same, by this definition, we cannot determine whether they are are equal or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's true for all $x$ except $2$, keeping in mind the discontinuity at $x=2$.